# C modifying register const char *

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering why you're allowed to modify a const variable if it's stored in a register, though it can be seen in some very extensively used code, such as (from http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/i386.subproj/strlen.c):

```
size_t
strlen(str)
    const char *str;
{
    register const char *s;

    for (s = str; *s; ++s);
    return(s - str);
}
```

It compiles without warning or error on gcc and clang.

Is there any particular reason you're allowed to modify it even though it's const?

Are there any other cases of being allowed to modify a const that I should be aware of (without ugly casting specifically meant to modify a const)?

Is there any reason why the example chose to qualify the variable as const?

Comment: `const` is postfix; as a special case it can be used prefix for base types such as `char` and `int`. So `const char` means `char const`, and `char const*` means “mutable pointer to immutable characters”. For “*immutable* pointer to immutable characters”, you would use `char const* const`.

Comment: In that case, why is const register char *p = 0; p++; allowed? the register should be const right?

Comment: `register` is a storage class specifier, which can go anywhere in the declaration specifier—informally, anywhere before the `*` in a pointer declaration. The `const` in your example still applies to the `char`, not to the pointer. So `p++` (advance the pointer) is allowed, but `*p++` (modify the character it points to) is not.

Comment: Ah thanks, are there any other cases where const can be used as a prefix?

Comment: @JonPurdy: I believe that you meant `(*p)++`, as `*p++` is effectively the same just as `*(p++)` (postfix operator has higher precedence).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: Yes, you’re right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following declaration:

```
register const char *s;
```

does not impute that pointer should be read-only itself, but it affects only to `char` objects, that it might point to. The following loop does not modify `*s`, but only the pointer itself (in other words value is safe).

```
for (s = str; *s; ++s)
    ;
```

Note that example utilizes old-style function declaration, that is not recommended in modern C, also `register` storage class does not mean, that value is actually stored in CPU register, it's just **hint** for compiler (and it can be ignored).

If you want to protect pointer itself, then correct declaration is:

```
register char * const s;
```

This can combined if you want to protect both referenced value and pointer with following declaration:

```
register const char * const s;
```

Comment: -1 To protect the pointer, `const` has to be on the *right* side of the asterisk: `char * const s;`. `char const *` is same as `const char *`.

Comment: On 21st century compilers, `register` **is** ignored. It's no longer a hint. Register assignment is essentially a solved problem.

Comment: @MSalters: It still might be useful for some embedded, low-level systems, but generally speaking you are right, compiler's optimizer is much far superior.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: Those systems have even less registers, making the optimal register assignment task even easier. The hard cases were SPARC server CPU's with 128 or 256 registers.

Answer (score 3):

I think what it's constant it's not the pointer, but the **pointed** char.

Comment: In that case, why is `const register char *p = 0; p++;` allowed?

Comment: Because in this line you are initializing the pointer, not the value. The pointer points to the address 0... I don't know what's the purpose of this piece of code, but that's what it's doing.

Comment: but why are you able to modify the register thus the `p++`

Comment: Because the register holds a pointer, not a value, and what its constant it's the pointed value, not the pointer...

Answer (score 0):

It is because const is referred to the pointed char and not the pointer.